# RichFaces 4 notification when uploading file

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a `<rich:fileUpload>` component and I want to show a notification when a file is rejected because the type is not allowed. I saw that RF has a `<rich:notifyMessage>` but I cannot render the message when a file is rejected. So far I have:

```
    <rich:fileUpload id="fileUploadComp"
                     addLabel="Agregar" clearAllLabel="Quitar todos"
                     clearLabel="Quitar" deleteLabel="Quitar"
                     doneLabel="Completado" uploadLabel="Subir archivos"
                     fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.doUpload}"
                     acceptedTypes="txt, csv" onclear="onclear(event);"
                     noDuplicate="true">
        <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="validationButton"/>
        <a4j:ajax event="typerejected" render="notificationFileRejected"/>
    </rich:fileUpload>

    <rich:notifyMessage for="fileUploadComp" 
                        id="notificationFileRejected"
                        sticky="true"
                        ajaxRendered="true"
                        title="Hello"/>
```

but I cannot see any notification globe when I choose a JPEG for instance.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

The main idea of this is to show a notification that tells the user something like "File type not allowed".

Any idea?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how can [`acceptedTypes`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_fileUpload.html) work for your use case? Uploading the whole content just for file type checking seems against performance optimization.

Comment: I don't think that works that way. I think that `rich:fileUpload` checks file's type before uploading.

Comment: rich:notifyMessage needs to consume a message. Did you check if there indeed is a message? rich:notifyMessages should show them. You might be able to generate a message by calling a backend method that then creates the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
<rich:fileUpload id="fileUploadComp"
                 addLabel="Agregar" clearAllLabel="Quitar todos"
                 clearLabel="Quitar" deleteLabel="Quitar"
                 doneLabel="Completado" uploadLabel="Subir archivos"
                 fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.doUpload}"
                 acceptedTypes="txt, csv" onclear="onclear(event);"
                 ontyperejected="ontyperejected();"
                 noDuplicate="true">
    <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="validationButton"/>
</rich:fileUpload>

<a4j:jsFunction name="ontyperejected" actionListener="#{uploadBean.setMessage()}"/>

<rich:notifyMessage stayTime="2000" nonblocking="true"/>
```

With java code:

```
public void setMessage() {
  String message="Wrong filetype...";
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("info", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, message));
}
```

MAG,
Milo van der Zee

Comment: This is it ! But still 2 things. First, is there a way to put that globe next to the fileUpload?, I want the user to be able to see it and in the upper right corner is not so visible----Second, When I select a file and it's rejected the message appears, but if I select again a wrong file the globe doesn't appear again, how to solve that?

Comment: Is the jsFunction and the backend called the second time? Maybe some css could help with the location of the messagebox.

Comment: Nope the Backing-bean isn't called the second time. Select fileA -> shows message -> Select again fileA -> no message. On the other hand, Select fileA -> shows message -> select fileB -> shows message -> select fileA -> shows message. If I select consecutively the same file only one notification appears (backing bean called once).

Comment: Then I think it is works-as-designed. The GUI already told the user that the file is not accepted or it doesn't even notice that it is another select. Might be an option to add a render="fileUploadComp" to the jsFunction. Could be that the file uploader is reinitialized then.

Comment: Did you try it with the render added?

Comment: the render added to the `<rich:notifyMessage>` ??

Comment: No, the render="fileUploadComp" for the jsFunction. That might reinitialize the rich:fileUpload component.

Comment: Another small matter is the 'best answer' mark. You still prefer your own? :)

Comment: I appreciate very much your help, but still is not what my users need, right now they prefer that alert box. If I can make it work the way they want (thanks to your help) I'll give you the best answer! All I can do is uncheck my answer :)

Comment: What is missing? What is the result of adding the render to the jsFunction?

Comment: There you go! Thanks a lot ! the render attrib was the 'missing' part ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well not as nice as I would have wanted but It does the trick.

```
    <rich:fileUpload id="fileUploadComp"
                     addLabel="Agregar" clearAllLabel="Quitar todos"
                     clearLabel="Quitar" deleteLabel="Quitar"
                     doneLabel="Completado" uploadLabel="Subir archivos"
                     fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.doUpload}"
                     acceptedTypes="txt, csv" onclear="onclear(event);"
                     ontyperejected="ontyperejected();"  //THIS IS MY TRICK
                     noDuplicate="true">
        <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="validationButton"/>
    </rich:fileUpload>

    <script>
        var ontyperejected = function(){
            alert('Archivo inválido. Tipos permitidos: .txt y .csv');
        }
    </script>
```

just create a JScript function and send an alert message. And voilà.
Still if someone know how to achieve that little pretty notification globe that appears and fades out I will be very thankful !